# Deployment of flask app with telebot to heroku results in Port 6000 is in use by another program

Tags: python, flask, heroku, telegram

I am trying to deploy my flask app to heroku, but every time I do so, I get this error

```
 * Serving Flask app 'app'
* Debug mode: off
Address already in use
Port 6000 is in use by another program. Either identify and stop that program, or start the server with a different port.
Worker exiting (pid: 122)
Worker (pid:122) exited with code 1
Worker (pid:122) exited with code 1.
Booting worker with pid: 127
```

and the port doesn't really matter, cause with any port happens the same, wether it is 6000 or 5000 or 5500 etc.

Here is my minimal code for reproducing

```
import os
import telebot
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
from flask import Flask, request

bot = telebot.TeleBot(os.getenv('BOT_TOKEN'))
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/' + os.getenv('BOT_TOKEN'), methods=['POST'])
def getMessage():
    json_string = request.get_data().decode('utf-8')
    update = telebot.types.Update.de_json(json_string)
    bot.process_new_updates([update])
    return "!", 200


@app.route('/'+ os.getenv('BOT_TOKEN')+ '/webhook', methods=['GET'])
def webhook_setup():
    bot.remove_webhook()
    bot.set_webhook(url='https://app-name.herokuapp.com/' + os.getenv('BOT_TOKEN'))


app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=6000)
```

This is my Procfile

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```